# Windows Task Scheduler Program Ends Immediately

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a Java executable (`.exe`) with a given JRE build in the same folder, which it uses to actually run.

I want to put this executable on Windows Task Scheduler.

I did some tests with some C++ hello world programs, and all went fine. This Java program, running directly (by two clicks or whatever) works all fine too (it is supposed to write to a file and end).

However, **when I put the Java program in the Task Scheduler, it exits immediately**, with status code `0x0` (success) and nothing is actually performed.

At Windows Task Manager, I see that `javaw.exe` starts and exits in a glimpse.

What could it be? Something related to Java? Something due to a specific task scheduler flag?

**Aditional**:

- Java executable built with `launch4j`.
- Scheduler set with `schtasks /create /tn MyETL /sc hourly /mo 3 /tr C:\ETL\etl.exe`

Comment: What is the command line you try to run from scheduler?

Comment: Possibly a dependency such as the CLASSPATH environment variable isn't getting set in the task scheduler process, or it's a PATH problem trying to find the JAR file.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto updated question

Comment: @selbie isn't a jar itself, I bundled the java app into executable `.exe`

Comment: Build a command file to call your exe and have the command redirect output to a file. Then schedule the command file. The output file should then provide some insight

Comment: Tried @ssc327 solution: a bat file like `etl.exe >> out.txt 2>&1`. The out file isn't even created. The scheduler now says it ended with `0x01` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that the problem was that the program was actually being executed in the wrong folder, in order that the output file wasn't where I thought it would.

The output file was being write in the starting folder, not the program's folder.

Answer (score 3):

When you run an application with Windows Scheduler, if that application has dependencies to other files via relative path, then you need to set the **start in** setting for the task. This sets the path from where execution will begin.

Alternatively you can use a command file and have it navigate to the correct directory first.

Comment: Thanks, this saved the day.